# XYZ color space for Display Device

Tags: color-management

Why is there a choice for XYZ color space for display device in Blender?

[image]

So CIE 1931 XYZ color space exists and there is some information about it online like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space). It seems to be an awesome color space that can define any color that is humanly possible to see (based on perceptions of 17 people observed by scientists of the year 1931) if I understand it correctly, but as far as I know, no display devices using it even exist. So why do we have it for display device in Blender?

Also, are there any good/common use cases for selecting it?

The question [What is the difference between color models (sRGB, Rec709, XYZ, ets) and which cases I need to prefer one of them?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129720/what-is-the-difference-between-color-models-srgb-rec709-xyz-ets-and-which-c) touches the subject, however there does not seem to be a real answer about the purpose of XYZ color space as a choice for Display Device and its intended or possible use cases.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://pasteboard.co/jesLOWrnlWIl.png take it with a grain of salt though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between color models (sRGB, Rec709, XYZ, ets) and which cases I need to prefer one of them?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129720/what-is-the-difference-between-color-models-srgb-rec709-xyz-ets-and-which-c)

Comment: @Emir The answers touch the subject, but this is a distinct question. I don't care much about it being closed, but would it be correct to close as a duplicate when it is a different question?.. It's specifically about XYZ color space and its purpose, not about what Display Device settings are for in general and the information provided there about this is vague and not really that specific. I have a feeling having XYZ is "hand-me-down hodgepodge" like Troy sais, but there must be more of an explanation about its existence... Wouldn't having a more in depth answer be nice to have on BSE?..